# Lotus Notes web application fails to launch

Tags: ibm-domino

There were a few changes that I made due to server vulnerability such as giving No Access to Anonymous for dbs: db4.nsf, admin4.nsf, decsdoc.nsf, lsxlc.nsf, lccon.nsf, domcfg.nsf, and agentlog.nsf.

Additionally, I set HTTPDISABLEMETHODS=TRACE in notes.ini as was suggested by my server team.

However, after http restart, my web application fails to launch.
I am using Notes 9.0.1 FP2. I soon realized that HTTPDISABLEMETHODS=TRACE is not required for this version.

I have since then, rolled back the changes and restarted the server, but it still doesn't work.
The server and applications are working in client but not on web.

I get the error: This site can't be reached. The connection was reset.

I don't know where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: I have already checked that HTTP Task is running.
HTTP Server Listen for connect requests on TCP Port: 443

My server team restored the OS image from the time previous to this change. That should have reset the application settings (if any were made). However, this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The port 443 was enabled and port 80 was disabled. Although this was a previous setting on which the application was working. Somehow, I thought to check what happens if Port 80 was enabled again.

And, the application started working. If I disable it again, it will stop working.
I don't know why. So, for now, this is the best case response that I have to resolve the issue.